# How do I display a scrollable list where it's grouped by two fields?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this data:

> `[{ID: 0, Line: 100, Part: 00-87000088, Lots: 00865756,00866790,00868501,00871385,00871905,00872712,00875997,00878042}, {ID: 1, Line: 990000, Part: 00-87000001, Lots: 00746727,00748270,00750627,00750632,00753983,00754156,00757423,00758997,00762736,00792476}]`

I need to display this in a scrollable widget like this:

```
Line      Part           Lots
100       00-87000088    00865756
                         00866790
                         00868501
                         00871385
                         00871905
                         00872712
                         00875997
                         00878042

990000    00-87000001    00746727          
                         00748270
                         00750627
                         00750632
                         00753983
                         00754156
                         00757423
                         00758997
                         00762736
                         00792476
```

The list of lots could be pretty long, that's why it needs to be scrollable. And the list of lots is dynamic, so I don't know the list ahead of time. How do I do this?

**What I've tried:**

```
//Populating the variables with data:
List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> lotsPicked = [];
var lines = [];
var parts = [];
var lots = [];

lotsPicked = await globals.issuePartsGetLots(wo: wo);

for (var element in lotsPicked) {
    lines.add(element['Line']);
    parts.add(element['Part']);
    lots.add(element['Lots']);
}

//Showing the data:
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: lotsPicked.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text(lines[index].toString()),
          Text(parts[index].toString()),
          Text(lots[index].toString()),
        ],
      );
      return Text(lotsPicked[index]['Line'].toString());
    },
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using ListView.builder Here is the code:

```
   class GroupedListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
    {
      'ID': 0,
      'Line': 100,
      'Part': '00-87000088',
      'Lots': [
        '00865756',
        '00866790',
        '00868501',
        '00871385',
        '00871905',
        '00872712',
        '00875997',
        '00878042',
      ],
    },
    {
      'ID': 1,
      'Line': 990000,
      'Part': '00-87000001',
      'Lots': [
        '00746727',
        '00748270',
        '00750627',
        '00750632',
        '00753983',
        '00754156',
        '00757423',
        '00758997',
        '00762736',
        '00792476',
      ],
    },
  ];

  GroupedListView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final line = data[index]['Line'];
        final part = data[index]['Part'];
        final lots = data[index]['Lots'];

        return Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              if (index == 0)
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    Text('Line'),
                    Text('Part'),
                    Text('Lots'),
                  ],
                ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('$line'),
                  Text('$part'),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: lots.map<Widget>((lot) {
                      return Text(lot);
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives an error: `Class 'String' has no instance method 'map'.
Receiver: "00865756,00866790,00868501,00871385,00871905,00872712,00875997,00878042"
Tried calling: map<Widget>(Closure: (dynamic) => Text)`

Comment: check my edited answer please

Comment: Still not working. The problem is that when I receive the data from the async function, `lots` is not a list. It is a single comma-delimited string. How do I split the string up into list before using it?

Comment: try this:
String commaSeparatedString = "value1,value2,value3";
List<String> myList = commaSeparatedString.split(",");

Answer (score 0):

You can create a itemBuilder for this.

```dart
class ItemBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemBuilder({
    Key? key,
    required this.line,
    required this.part,
    required this.parts,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int line;
  final String part;
  final List<String> parts;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('$line'),
        Text('$part'),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: parts.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
        )
      ].map((e) => Expanded(child: e)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

And for the header include extend one item

```dart
 ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 10 + 1,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text('line'),
          Text('part'),
          Text('parts'),
        ].map((e) => Expanded(child: e)).toList(),
      );
    }
    return ItemBuilder(
      line: index - 1, // -1 because of the header
      part: 'part',
      parts: List.generate(3, (index) => 'part $index'),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: Something about this is not right. The 3rd column should show the lots in a column with the commas removed, but this is showing the part number.

Comment: you can process data on `parts` sections